# Raising AttributeError has unexpected side effects with @properties

Tags: python

Given a contrived Python class:

```
class Item(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print("In __getattr__ looking for '{}'".format(name))
        if name.startswith("exists"):
            return "Here's a dummy string"
        message = "'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(type(self).__name__, name)
        raise AttributeError(message)

    def thing_a(self):
        return self.thing_b()

    def thing_b(self):
        return self.nonexistent_thing()
```

Calling `Item().thing_a()` produces the expected output:

```
In __getattr__ looking for 'nonexistent_thing'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug.py", line 13, in <module>
    Item().thing_a()
  File "debug.py", line 8, in thing_a
    return self.thing_b()
  File "debug.py", line 11, in thing_b
    return self.nonexistent_thing()
  File "debug.py", line 5, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(message)
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'nonexistent_thing'
```

However, I really want `thing_a`, `thing_b`, and `nonexistent_thing` to be properties. So, if I change my code to:

```
class Item(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print("In __getattr__ looking for '{}'".format(name))
        if name.startswith("exists"):
            return "Here's a dummy string"
        message = "'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(type(self).__name__, name)
        raise AttributeError(message)

    @property
    def thing_a(self):
        return self.thing_b

    @property
    def thing_b(self):
        return self.nonexistent_thing
```

and call `Item().thing_a`, I get an unexpected result:

```
In __getattr__ looking for 'nonexistent_thing'
In __getattr__ looking for 'thing_b'
In __getattr__ looking for 'thing_a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug.py", line 15, in <module>
    Item().thing_a
  File "debug.py", line 5, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(message)
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'thing_a'
```

Uh-oh... the `print()` output appears to be the reverse of the execution order, and the message for `AttributeError` is for `thing_a`, which does exist.

During my experimentation to figure this out, I discovered that changing `AttributeError` to a plain old `Exception` makes everything work ok:

```
In __getattr__ looking for 'nonexistent_thing'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug.py", line 15, in <module>
    Item().thing_a
  File "debug.py", line 9, in thing_a
    return self.thing_b
  File "debug.py", line 13, in thing_b
    return self.nonexistent_thing
  File "debug.py", line 5, in __getattr__
    raise Exception(message)
Exception: 'Item' object has no attribute 'nonexistent_thing'
```

So, it seems `AttributeError` itself doesn't play well with `@property`, possibly because it's being caught somewhere by the `property` object. But `AttributeError` appears to be the most appropriate exception for `__getattr__` to raise, and it's not ideal to raise an `Exception` without subclassing.

Is anyone able to shed some light on this problem, and know of a way to have `@property` and `__getattr__` with `AttributeError` work together in harmony?

I've tried this in Python 2.7 and 3.6.

**EDIT:** Added (contrived) logic for `__getattr__` to respond to if `name` starts with `"exists"`. I **do** want it to fail for `nonexistent_thing`, but I want it to raise `AttributeError` at the correct time with the correct `name`.

Comment: @jedwards, given that this is a contrived example, I didn't flesh out `__getattr__` fully. I've added a comment to show where the real logic would go. (Edit: @jedwards has since deleted their comment)

Comment: Pretty important to show that actual logic. In particular, whether it calls the super implementation of not is pretty crucial.

Comment: @MadPhysicist the code is a minimal working example and will fail in and of itself. But, FWIW, my real code doesn't call `super()`.

Answer (score 1):

The missing piece to the puzzle is that `@property` is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) (an object which implements `__get__` / `__set__` / `__del__` to participate in attribute lookup).

Implementation of descriptors is done via the `__getattribute__` magic method.

The important bit of the implementation here from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) (emphasis mine):

> Called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses for instances of the class. If the class also defines `__getattr__()`, the latter will not be called unless `__getattribute__()` either calls it explicitly **or raises an AttributeError**.

To illustrate with your example a little further:

```
class Item(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print(f'__getattribute__ {name}')
        try:
            return super().__getattribute__(name)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'{e} during __getattribute__ {name}')
            raise

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print("In __getattr__ looking for '{}'".format(name))
        # useful logic here which might return a value...
        message = "'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(type(self).__name__, name)
        raise AttributeError(message)

    @property
    def thing_a(self):
        return self.thing_b

    @property
    def thing_b(self):
        return self.nonexistent_thing


Item().thing_a
```

The call sequence goes:

```
- __getattribute__(thing_a)
  - property.__get__(...)
    - thing_a
      - __getattriute__(thing_b)
        - property.__get__(...)
          - thing_B
            - __getattribute__(nonexistent_thing)
            - (raised AE) -> __getattr__(nonexistent_thing)
      - (raised AE) -> __getattr_(thing_b)
- (raised AE) -> getattr(thing_a)
```

The calls to `__getattr__` are in response to `AttributeError`s during descriptor resolution in `__getattribute__`.

Here's the output of the above python snippet:

```
__getattribute__ thing_a
__getattribute__ thing_b
__getattribute__ nonexistent_thing
'Item' object has no attribute 'nonexistent_thing' during __getattribute__ nonexistent_thing
In __getattr__ looking for 'nonexistent_thing'
'Item' object has no attribute 'nonexistent_thing' during __getattribute__ thing_b
In __getattr__ looking for 'thing_b'
'Item' object has no attribute 'thing_b' during __getattribute__ thing_a
In __getattr__ looking for 'thing_a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 25, in <module>
    Item().thing_a
  File "t.py", line 14, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(message)
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'thing_a'
```

Comment: There's nothing special about property being a descriptor. Methods are  descriptors too

Comment: @MadPhysicist there is in this case though, methods don't raise in the `__get__` call

Comment: Thanks both @Anthony Sottile and @Mad Physicist for the great answers explaining how this problem comes about. Is there a canonical way to fix it, other than using another subclass of `Exception` instead of `AttributeError`?

Comment: @tristanm. I am not sure you really have a problem here. If you do `x.thing_a`, you do *not* expect to see an error message saying "attribute blah_blah_blah not found". You should not be exposing implementation details and the user should not care *why* they can't access `thing_a`. In that sense, the existing error message is correct. If you really want a detailed exception, though, just don't raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Yes you do, because the programmer needs to know where they've gone wrong. In my case, I haven't implemented `nonexistent_thing` yet, or I've made a typo. But the exception ultimately raised says `AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'thing_a'`, which __does__ exist. The actual error is because `nonexistent_thing` does not exist, so the exception should really say `AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'nonexistent_thing'`. Otherwise, the message is just a red herring.

Comment: It's the same as `def x: return {}["something"]` telling me that `x does not exist` when calling `x()`. The actual error is a `KeyError` because `something` doesn't exist for this empty `dict`, so telling me that the method encompassing the error doesn't exist is really not helpful.